# UPDATE two columns with new value under large size table

Tags: sql

We have table like :

```
mytable (pid, string_value, int_value)
```

This table has more than 20M rows in total. Now we have a feature try to mark all the rows from this tables as invalid. So we need update the table columns: `string_Value = NULL and int_value = 0` which indicate this is invalid row ( we still want to keep the pid as it is important to us)

So what is the best way?

I use the following SQL:

```
UPDATE Mytable 
SET string_value = NULL,
    int_value = 0;
```

but this query takes more than 4 minutes in my test env. Is there any better way we can improve it?

Comment: . . Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: You can test updating in chunks. Like 25000 rows per transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating all the rows can be quite expensive.  Often, it is faster to empty the table and reload it.

In generic SQL this looks like:

```
create table mytable_temp as
    select pid
    from mytable;

truncate table mytable;  -- back it up first!

insert into mytable (pid, string_value, int_value)
    select pid, null, 0
    from mytable_temp;
```

The creation of the temporary table may use different syntax, depending on our database.

Answer (score 0):

Updates can take time to complete. Another way of achieving this is to follow the following steps:

1. Add new columns with the values you need set as the default value
2. Drop the original columns
3. Rename the new columns with the names of the original columns.
4. You can then drop the default values on the new columns.

This needs to be tested as different DBMSs allow different levels of table alters (i.e. not all DMBSs allow a drop default or a drop column).